# "~/.wine is not owned by you", am I safe?

Tags: wine, sudo, security, malware

So I was running about trying to install something in wine when I encountered the suggestion to use sudo to get administrator privileges. That's when I got the above message

```
~/.wine is not owned by you
```

Reading up I quickly realised why this message appears and that trying to `sudo` wine is **A REALLY BAD IDEA**.

So I didn't do anything further and don't intend to ever `sudo` wine again. My question is, because I received this block, am I safe? Or do I need to remove all of wine because I did?

Comment: Is it really `/.wine` or `~/.wine`? I'm pretty sure there shouldn't be a `.wine` directory right under the root. Or is there some chrooting I'm not aware of?

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, don't ever run Wine as root. On a related point, if you ever need to run a GUI app (e.g. `gedit`) as root, please remember to use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`. This protects your home folder from such problems.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wine expects that `$WINEPREFIX` (which defaults to `~/.wine`) be owned by you. When you run wine with `sudo`, `~/.wine` is owned by **you**, but wine is running as **root**. Hence the error. Wine immediately quits when this happens, so you don't need to worry, no damage was done.

You don't need to reset ownerships as in [Zanna's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/894878/158442) (this particular run of wine didn't make any changes), but that's usually harmless.

Note that Wine applications have as much access to the system as the user they run as, so running Wine as root, as you have realised, is dangerous.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Do not use `sudo wine application.exe`, just `wine application.exe`

Answer (score 18):

Nothing too terrible has happened ;) root might have become owner of the wine config directory, that's all.

You can fix any potential issues by making sure you **are** the owner of that directory. When logged in on your normal user account, run (typing **very** carefully):

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.wine
```

Comment: Whoa! It's very plausible that there are things in my `$HOME` that I don't own! For instance, how about that symbolic link to `"$SHARED_WALLPAPERS"` or `/usr/bin`? Please don't advise `chown -R "$USER:" "$HOME"`.

Comment: @Zanna merely creating a link like that doesn't let you change ownerships on it (or edit files in it), but the `sudo` here makes it tricky.

Comment: @wchargin `chown -R` does not descend into symbolic links. (You may have seen something in the manpage about the default behavior being to dereference symbolic links; this refers to links specified on the command line rather than those found via recursion - the options for recursion are further down)

Comment: @Random832 still a problem for bind mounts and the like.

Comment: @muru I think at that point we're talking about setups so unusual that the person who made them probably knows what they're doing.

Comment: @Random832: Good to know—thanks. Indeed, I misunderstood that. I still wouldn't advise it for the reason that the directory structure itself may have nonhomogeneous owner.